# zf2 combine two or more where predicate

Tags: php, zend-framework, where-clause

I have a Zend\Db\Sql\Where look like this:

```
$where->nest()->like()->and->like()->unnest()->or->equalTo();
```

And then i want to add one more predicate look like this:

```
$where->and->greaterThan()...
```

But the problem is the 'and' in the above line does not apply on the whole where cluase. the result is :

```
(like and like) OR equalTo AND greaterThan
```

But what i want is:

```
( (like and like) OR equal ) AND greaterThan
```

How should i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to double nest. In your final example you have two opening parentheses. This is a double nest ;)

```
$where->->nest()->nest()->like()->and->like()->unnest()->or->equalTo();
```

And

```
$where->unnest()->and->greaterThan()...
```

You should be fine with this.